# Is closure property guaranteed in finite sets?

Tags: group-theory

This is in context of residue classes in group theory.

Consider a finite set $G$ with a composition (multiplication for the sake of this problem). If I take any two elements in the set and perform multiplication operation on them, is it guaranteed that the result will be in $G$?

i.e.

Let $a,b\in G$. Then is it guaranteed that $a*b\in G$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, what exactly is your definition of "composition"?

Comment: @morrowmh by composition, the author means any operation on the set G. He has taken the example of multiplication here. Please let me know if I am missing out on something as well. I am very new to modern algebra.

Comment: The finiteness of the set $G$ is not relevant here.

Comment: And saying "by composition he/she means any operation" just moves the point about *the definition* from the word "composition" to the one "operation". The answer below gives the definition of composition/operation, and the closure is then part of it.

Comment: Well, what exactly is your definition of "operation"?

Comment: The confusion may come from unfamiliarity with reading math. The phrase *a finite set with a composition* means something more than the conjunction of *a finite set* and *a composition*. The subset of reals $G=\{1,2\}$ is clearly finite. The real numbers can be composed by multiplication. yet, $G$ is NOT a finite set with a composition. This is because multiplication is not an operation of the set $G$ (but of a bigger set). Summary: in my somewhat educated opinion closure is implicitly covered by the phrase *a finite set with a compostion*. By definition.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, a composition or multiplication is a function $G\times G\to G$. So, necessarily the image is contained in $G$, meaning $a\cdot b\in G$ for all $a,b\in G$.